# Django not connecting to RDS Mysql

Tags: python, mysql, django, amazon-ec2, rds

I am trying to deploy my django app on EC2 and am using RDS(Mysql) as the backend.

However when I try to run gunicorn with this, the server does not respond, and the if I run python manage.py dbshell I get the error:

**CommandError: You appear not to have the 'mysql' program installed or on your path.**

It seems to be trying to connect to a local server of mysql when I have clearly changed the host setting the Database dict to my RDS deployment

Things I have done for solving this and trouble shooting:
1. I have changed the database settings so that they point to the RDS   database.

2. Both the EC2 and the RDS instance are in the same zone of AWS(read this might have been the issue)
3. Permission could have been a problem, but I checked by trying to login from my local machine, and I was able to access the mysql commandline on my server.
4. Checked the database settings which django is picking up at runtime,they are correct.
5. Install Mysql-python, it would not install without a local installation of Mysql, so googled that , people suggested install libmysqlclient-dev first  and then you should be able to install Mysql-python.

Has someone face a similar problem? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You know the answer "so googled that , people suggested install libmysqlclient-dev first and then you should be able to install Mysql-python."

Comment: Yeah but that's not the issue. Once I am able to install Mysql python django should run normally, but it looks for a local installation of MySQL instead of connecting to the RDS hosted My SQL

Comment: Do you have a local mysql instance that you could try? Eliminating as many steps as possible is crucial to debugging.

Comment: It's not looking for a mysql server locally. It's looking for the mysql client library. Without the mysql client library you cannot use any mysql api. They all depend on it

Comment: Yes, I tried it on my dev environment using a local mysql setup and it works fine.

Comment: @Avneesh did you find the solution? I am having the same issue now. My django app on ec2 tries to connect local DB instead of RDS. However, in my local machine, it works fine.